# How can i write the numbers from the 2d int array to the exact place in a text file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a text file and this is the content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Test
{
    class test1
    {
        int[,] map = new int[,] 
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
};
```

And i have a code where i create 2d int array from bitmap pixels values.

```
private void CreateArray(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            ret = new int[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];

            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (color.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
                    {
                        ret[x, y] = 0;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        ret[x, y] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now if i will loop over the ret like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < ret.GetLength(0); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < ret.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    var val = ret[k, l];
                }
            }
```

So once val will be 1 then 1 then 1 then 1 then 0,0,0,0 then 1,1 and so on.
I need to take this 0,1 numbers from the array and write them instead the 0 and 1 numbers in the text file in here:

```
int[,] map = new int[,] 
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
    };
```

So in the end when i will look at the text file again i will for example it:

```
int[,] map = new int[,] 
    {
        {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,},
    };
```

I need to replace in the text file only the 0 and 1 numbers with those in the ret array.
Maybe i instead replacing somehow to write the ret array so it will by displayed on the text file like in the examples i gave.

But in the end it should be as i show in the example.

EDIT

I have two text files i will merge to one later.
The first text file is the top it's:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

    namespace Test
    {
        class test1
        {
            int[,] map = new int[,] 
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
    };
```

The second text file contain the rest of the code loops constructor and other things of this class.
In the end i will have one text file with the code inside and what i need to update/change is only the numbers in the array map

But i want to keep the format as it is in the text file:

```
int[,] map = new int[,] 
        {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
        };
```

Only the numbers 0 and 1 will be changed/replace with those i have in the 2d int array variable ret.
I can make the first text file also with empty map array like this:

```
int[,] map = new int[,] 
            {

            };
```

And then to insert/add the numbers 0 and 1 from ret to the text file so in the end it will will be like this:

```
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
```

In any case i need to keep text fiel format as it is in my example with the map array and only the 0 and 1 numbers change.

Comment: It's confusing, you have a text file that has c# code and you have some other code that is writing to the text file ?

Comment: In the current project where i create the 2d int array i need to update the text file to replace the numbers then i'm using the text file in another project i have.

Comment: Its like creating a new CS file. I have two text files this one and another one with the rest of the code and i merge this two text files to one later. Then i use the merged text file as CS in another project with the code in it. The only thing that should be changed is the numbers in the array in the first text file . What i need is know how to replace the numbers or create that kind of array in the text file with the numbers i have in ret.

Comment: Code to replace text at specific locations in an existing file will be more complicated than keeping a text file with only the pixel values and loading your array from it. You must also realize that after you change the text in your file, you would need to recompile it.

Comment: I know i will need to recompile it later thats not the problem to use the file later in another project. The problem is how to create this text file with the map array with the numbers i have in ret ? Maybe not replacing the 0 and 1 but creating all the text file over again and make the ret variable to be written to the text file in the format in my example.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest, use a Regex to isolate the 0,1 lines, then do some work on them, 
and later overwrite the file, eg:

```
string[] Reader = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile);
Regex 10line = new Regex(@"{\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d,\d},")

foreach (string Line ind Reader) {
if 10line.isMatch(Line.trim());
doSomethingWith(Line);
}
writeNewFile();
```